# Printing in Universal Apps

Tags: c#, printing, uwp

I'm developing a Windows 10 Universal App that needs to perform calculations and generate a printout based on the results. I don't know where to get started with printing. What is the easiest way to create a new document? In WPF we had FixedDocument and FlowDocument. I don't see those available in the Universal App format.

Answer (score 4):

Declare the `PrintManager` and `PrintDocument`. The `PrintManager` type is in the `Windows.Graphics.Printing` namespace along with types to support other Windows printing functionality. The `PrintDocument` type is in the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Printing` namespace along with other types that support preparing XAML content for printing. You can make it easier to write your printing code by adding the following using or Imports statements to your page.

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
```

The `PrintDocument` class is used to handle much of the interaction between the app and the `PrintManager`, but it exposes several callbacks of its own. During registration, create instances of `PrintManager` and `PrintDocument` and register handlers for their printing events.
In the **`UWP`** print sample, registration is performed by the `RegisterForPrinting` method.

```
public virtual void RegisterForPrinting()
{
   printDocument = new PrintDocument();
   printDocumentSource = printDocument.DocumentSource;
   printDocument.Paginate += CreatePrintPreviewPages;
   printDocument.GetPreviewPage += GetPrintPreviewPage;
   printDocument.AddPages += AddPrintPages;

   PrintManager printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
   printMan.PrintTaskRequested += PrintTaskRequested;
}
```

When the user goes to a page that supports, it initiates the registration within the OnNavigatedTo method.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   // Initalize common helper class and register for printing
   printHelper = new PrintHelper(this);
   printHelper.RegisterForPrinting();

   // Initialize print content for this scenario
   printHelper.PreparePrintContent(new PageToPrint());

   // Tell the user how to print
   MainPage.Current.NotifyUser("Print contract registered with customization, use the Print button to print.", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
}
```

When the user leaves the page, disconnect the printing event handlers. If you have a multiple-page app and don't disconnect printing, an exception is thrown when the user leaves the page and then comes back to it.

You can read more on [Print from your app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204545.aspx) and also find the TIP: *Tip  Most of the examples in this topic are based on the print sample. To see the full code, download the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) print sample from the Windows-universal-samples repo on GitHub.*

Comment: This is verbatim off the Microsoft website. I tried copying and pasting this code into my 'MainPage' class, but it was riddled with red underlines and won't even compile. A little more practical guidance on how to implement this code in a simple app would be appreciated.

Comment: How to add reference for 'PrintHelper' class ?

Answer (score 0):

GetPrintPreviewPage event is fierd once time for each page, when i return to a page the event not fierd.
I use this code to persist the current preview page.

private async void PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage(object p_sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs p_args)
        {
            SelectedPagePreview = p_args.PageNumber;

i am testing on a windows 8.1 & tablet x64.